# How to update filed type from string to array of strings in elasticsearch?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have an index filled by data with this schema:

```
{
    "name" : "string",
    "book": "string"
}
```

And I am working with ElasticSearch with Nest and C#.
Now because of the business requirement book field must be an array and I Update my query model C# POCO class but when I run my query I am getting this error:

> expected:'[', actual:'"test"', at offset:2248

Now I want to Update my schema to convert the book to array type. I try to use script and mapping but could not find a good solution? is there any working method to perform this change in ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 1):

ES has built in functionally for docs update by query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html.

In case above query will look like this:

```
POST my-index-000001/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": " ctx._source.book = [ctx._source.book] ",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all":{}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot update or change field type in mapping(schema) of indices that has been created.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#updating-field-mappings

if you need change type, you should create new indices and use Reindex API.

Comment: there is another solution.  you can add a new field with name of book_array. you cant change existing field but you can add new field.

Comment: I solved this by reading all documents by the first model and updating data with the second model in c# code. But I was searching for a built-in solution in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

To complement Nazar's answer

Depend on the official doc of Elasticsearch, there is no dedicated array data type in ES, so you don't need to change mapping, you just need to give an array value to that field.

Here is the ref:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html